# Access multiple (row, column) combinations in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm just starting out with numpy and can't find a simple solution to this problem.

Simple example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2], [-1, 5], [0, 12]])
x1 = (0, 0)
x2 = (1, 1)
x3 = (2, 0)
A[x1]  # 1
A[x2]  # 5
A[x3]  # 0
```

I'd like to somehow put my tuples x1, x2, x3 into a single object, which I would then use to index into A.  I'd like this to return [1, 5, 0] -- hence the title, accessing multiple (row, column) combinations in a numpy array.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Here's what I've tried:

```
A[[x1, x2, x3]]  # IndexError
A[(x1, x2, x3)]  # IndexError
A[x1, x2, x3]  # IndexError
A[np.array((x1, x2, x3))]  # Not what I'm trying to do
```

One possibility is:

```
tuples = (x1, x2, x3)
elems = []
for tup in tuples:
    elems.append(A[tup])

B = np.array(elems)
B  # [1, 5, 0] as desired
```

But is there a way to avoid the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [1357]: A[zip(x1,x2,x3)]
Out[1357]: array([1, 5, 0])
```